# How to define a protocol to include a property with @Published property wrapper

Tags: protocols, swiftui, combine

When using @Published property wrapper following current SwiftUI syntax, it seems very hard to define a protocol that includes a property with @Published, or I definitely need help :)

As I'm implementing dependency injection between a View and it's ViewModel, I need to define a ViewModelProtocol so to inject mock data to preview easily.

This is what I first tried,

```
protocol PersonViewModelProtocol {
    @Published var person: Person
}
```

I get "Property 'person' declared inside a protocol cannot have a wrapper".

Then I tried this,

```
protocol PersonViewModelProtocol {
    var $person: Published
}
```

Obviously didn't work because '$' is reserved.

I'm hoping a way to put a protocol between View and it's ViewModel and also leveraging the elegant @Published syntax. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm really hoping this becomes possible as I have the same issue. I ended up using `CurrentValueSubject` for my properties instead of `@Published` as that can happily be used in a protocol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57657870/12106051

Answer (score 29):

You have to be explicit and describe all synthetized properties:

```swift
protocol WelcomeViewModel {
    var person: Person { get }
    var personPublished: Published<Person> { get }
    var personPublisher: Published<Person>.Publisher { get }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var person: Person = Person()
    var personPublished: Published<Person> { _person }
    var personPublisher: Published<Person>.Publisher { $person }
}
```

Comment: When updating the `ViewModel` which property do you set? The `. person `, `. personPublished ` or `. personPublisher `?

Answer (score 21):

My MVVM approach:

```swift
// MARK: View

struct ContentView<ViewModel: ContentViewModel>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.name)
            TextField("", text: $viewModel.name)
                .border(Color.black)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: ContentViewModelMock())
    }
}

// MARK: View model

protocol ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var name: String { get set }
}

final class ContentViewModelImpl: ContentViewModel {
    @Published var name = ""
}

final class ContentViewModelMock: ContentViewModel {
    var name: String = "Test"
}
```

How it works:

- `ViewModel` protocol inherits `ObservableObject`, so `View` will subscribe to `ViewModel` changes
- property `name` has getter and setter, so we can use it as `Binding`
- when `View` changes `name` property (via TextField) then View is notified about changes via `@Published` property in `ViewModel` (and UI is updated)
- create `View` with either real implementation or mock depending on your needs

Possible downside: `View` has to be generic.

Comment: Pretty much the solution I was looking for, much appreciated! Makes complete sense, Published will force the entire ObservableObject (viewModel) to trigger the refresh.

Comment: Not a good solution if you have a big view model. We just need to listen to 'name' here. Why listen to the changes of the whole view model?

Answer (score 9):

A workaround my coworker came up with is to use a base class that declares the property wrappers, then inherit it in the protocol. It still requires inheriting it in your class that conforms to the protocol as well, but looks clean and works nicely.

```
class MyPublishedProperties {
    @Published var publishedProperty = "Hello"
}

protocol MyProtocol: MyPublishedProperties {
    func changePublishedPropertyValue(newValue: String)
}

class MyClass: MyPublishedProperties, MyProtocol {
    changePublishedPropertyValue(newValue: String) {
        publishedProperty = newValue
    }
}
```

Then in implementation:

```
class MyViewModel {
    let myClass = MyClass()

    myClass.$publishedProperty.sink { string in
        print(string)
    }

    myClass.changePublishedPropertyValue("World")
}

// prints:
//    "Hello"
//    "World"
```

Answer (score 8):

This is how I suppose it should be done:

```swift
public protocol MyProtocol {
    var _person: Published<Person> { get set }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol, ObservableObject {
    @Published var person: Person

    public init(person: Published<Person>) {
        self._person = person
    }
}
```

Although the compiler seems to sort of like it (the "type" part at least), there is a mismatch in the property's access control between the class and the protocol (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html). I tried different combinations: `private`, `public`, `internal`, `fileprivate`. But none worked. Might be a bug? Or missing functionality?

Comment: I have run into the same access control problem you've described. Do you have a resolution for this problem? Or, do we expand the protocol to include the wrapped and projected values be conformed manually?

Comment: Looks like this behaviour is debated hotly in the [swift evolution proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0258-property-wrappers-second-review/25843/14). Sadly, it seems like whatever the access level of the published variable is, the synthesised variables are either private or internal(I'm confused by some terminologies there).

Answer (score 2):

Until 5.2 we don't have support for property wrapper. So it's necessary expose manually the publisher property.

```
protocol PersonViewModelProtocol {
    var personPublisher: Published<Person>.Publisher { get }
}

class ConcretePersonViewModelProtocol: PersonViewModelProtocol {
    @Published private var person: Person

    // Exposing manually the person publisher 
    var personPublisher: Published<Person>.Publisher { $person }
    
    init(person: Person) {
        self.person = person
    }

    func changePersonName(name: String) {
        person.name = name
    }
}

final class PersonDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let viewModel = ConcretePersonViewModelProtocol(person: Person(name: "Joao da Silva", age: 60))

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    func bind() {
        viewModel.personPublisher
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { person in
                print(person.name)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        viewModel.changePersonName(name: "Joao dos Santos")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered this as well. As of Catalina beta7, there doesn't seem to be any workaround, so our solution is to add in a conformance via an extension like so:

```swift
struct IntView : View {
    @Binding var intValue: Int

    var body: some View {
        Stepper("My Int!", value: $intValue)
    }
}

protocol IntBindingContainer {
    var intValue$: Binding<Int> { get }
}

extension IntView : IntBindingContainer {
    var intValue$: Binding<Int> { $intValue }
}
```

While this is a bit of extra ceremony, we can then add in functionality to all the `IntBindingContainer` implementations like so:

```swift
extension IntBindingContainer {
    /// Reset the contained integer to zero
    func resetToZero() {
        intValue$.wrappedValue = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a fairly clean workaround by creating a generic `ObservableValue` class that you can include in your protocols.

I am unsure if there are any major drawbacks to this, but it allows me to easily create mock/injectable implementations of my protocol while still allowing use of published properties.

```swift
import Combine

class ObservableValue<T> {
    @Published var value: T
    
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    var name: ObservableValue<String> { get }
    var age: ObservableValue<Int> { get }
}

class MyImplementation: MyProtocol {
    var name: ObservableValue<String> = .init("bob")
    var age: ObservableValue<Int> = .init(29)
}

class MyViewModel {
    let myThing: MyProtocol = MyImplementation()
    
    func doSomething() {
        let myCancellable = myThing.age.$value
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { val in
                print(val)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the drawback could be the inability to use the published value as a Binding, or at least I haven't figured out a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following set up should do.

- Declare a `ViewState` class with `@Published` properties
- Declare a `ViewModel` protocol with a `ViewState` property requirement.
- Create a `ViewModel` instance and supply its `ViewState` instance to `View`, which shall observe the same.

ViewModel.swift

```swift
class ViewState {
    @Published fileprivate(set) var text: String = ""
    @Published fileprivate(set) var number: Int = 0
}

protocol ViewModel {
    var viewState: ViewState { get }
}
```

ViewModelImpl.swift

```swift
class ViewModelImpl: ViewModel {
    var viewState = ViewState()
    
    func onSomeChange() {
        viewState.text = "abc"
        viewState.number = 1
    }
}
```

View.swift

```swift
class View: UIView { //It can also be UIViewController. Shown UIView for simplicity.
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []
    var viewState: ViewState? = nil {
        didSet {
            cancellables.removeAll()
            guard let viewState else { return }
            var textCancellable = viewState.$text.sink { recievedText in
                print("Do something")
            }
            var numberCancellable = viewState.$number.sink { recievedNumber in
                print("Do something")
            }
            cancellables = [textCancellable, numberCancellable]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - View Model

final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var value: Int = 0

    func increment() {
        value += 1
    }
}

extension MyViewModel: MyViewViewModel { }

// MARK: - View

protocol MyViewViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var value: Int { get }

    func increment()
}

struct MyView<ViewModel: MyViewViewModel>: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("\(viewModel.value)")

            Button("Increment") {
                self.viewModel.increment()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

I succeeded in just requiring the plain variable, and by adding the @Published in the fulfilling class:

```
final class CustomListModel: IsSelectionListModel, ObservableObject {



    @Published var list: [IsSelectionListEntry]


    init() {

        self.list = []
    }
...
```

```
protocol IsSelectionListModel {


    var list: [IsSelectionListEntry] { get }
...
```