# onReceive called infinitely in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting an infinite loop, onReceive is called infinitely when using a protocol with @Published variable. To use @Published variable in a protocol I am using this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58471595/5881884). 
This line in MyImageView:

```
if self.viewModel.answered {
```

seems to cause a call in

```
onReceive { self.viewModel.objectWillChange
```

inside ContentView.

Any idea how to make this work?

This is the entire code:

EnvObject:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {
    var answered: Bool { get set }
    var answeredPublished: Published<Bool> { get }
    var answeredPublisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher { get }
}

class GameViewModel: ObservableObject & MyProtocol {

    @Published var answered = false
    var answeredPublished: Published<Bool> { _answered }
    var answeredPublisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher { $answered }

}
```

Views:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyImageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GameViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if self.viewModel.answered {
            print("not nil")
            return AnyView(Image("clearImage")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            )
        }
        else {
            print("nil")
            return AnyView(
                Text(self.viewModel.answered ? "true" : "false")
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ViewBelow<ViewModel: ObservableObject & MyProtocol>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("below")
        .onReceive(self.viewModel.objectWillChange,

           perform: { _ in
               print("onReceive target")
           }
        )
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geo in
            VStack {
                MyImageView()

                ViewBelow<GameViewModel>()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate
    import UIKit
    import SwiftUI

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(GameViewModel())

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it is not. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 - works as expected. I just added `.onTapGesture` to `MyImageView()` to test `answered` change.

Comment: what is the idea behind your MyProtocol? I am lost a little bit ...

Comment: @user3441734 : I have updated the Views code, now the reason behind the protocol should be clearer.

Comment: @Asperi : I am using XCode 11.3.1 and iPhone 8 simulator (13.3) and I am getting the infinite loop. Can you verify with the updated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
class MyPublishedProperties {
    @Published var answered = false
}

protocol MyProtocol: MyPublishedProperties {
    func changePublishedPropertyValue(newValue: Bool)
}


class GameViewModel: ObservableObject & MyPublishedProperties, MyProtocol {

    func changePublishedPropertyValue(newValue: Bool) {
        answered = newValue
    }
}
```