# Swift Combine: turn a publisher into a read-only CurrentValueSubject

Tags: swift, combine

Sometimes my viewmodel uses a `@Published` property or a `PassthroughSubject`, but I don't want this to be writeable to the outside world. Easy enough, turn it into a public `AnyPublisher` and keep the writable one private, like this:

```swift
class ViewModel {
  @Published private var _models = ["hello", "world"]

  var models: AnyPublisher<[String], Never> {
    return $_models.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
viewModel.models.sink { print($0) }
```

But what if you want to be able to read the value "on demand" as well? For example for this situation:

```swift
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(viewModel.models[indexPath.row])
  }
}
```

Obviously, the above code doesn't work.

I thought about using a `CurrentValueSubject`, but its value is writable too, plus I'm having a hard time turning a Publisher into a CurrentValueSubject anyway.

My current solution is to add something like this on the viewmodel:

```swift
class ViewModel {
  @Published private var _models = ["hello", "world"]
  @Published var selectedIndex: Int?

  var models: AnyPublisher<[String], Never> {
    return $_models.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

  var selectedModel: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
    return models.combineLatest($selectedIndex.compactMap { $0 }).map { value, index in
      value[index]
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
viewModel.models.sink { print($0) }

viewModel.selectedModel.sink { print($0) }
viewModel.selectedIndex = 1
```

But it's a bit of a chore to add the `selectedIndex` property, the `selectedModel` publisher, set the selectedIndex and subscribe to the publisher.. all because I want to be able to read the current value of `viewModel.models` (and not have it writable).

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you simply keep the `@Published` property public, while making its setter private? That should suit your requirements perfectly while also keeping your code minimal and clean.

```
class ViewModel {
  @Published public private(set) var models = ["hello", "world"]
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
viewModel.$models.sink { print($0) }
```

Comment: ...I never realized I could do that ‍♂️

Comment: @KevinRenskers I guess because Swift auto-synthesises getters and setters, unless you see it possible to add different accessibility modifiers to them, you wouldn't even think it's possible.

Comment: The problem here is that you can't define your `var` in a `protocol` if it is `@Published`, so you can't achieve abstraction, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @bkbeachlabs you can't add property wrappers to protocol definitions, but you can still define `@Published` property requirements in protocols with a bit of extra code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58471595/4667835) for how to do that. Btw, protocols are not the only way to achieve abstraction.