# Read only CurrentValueSubject?

Tags: swift, combine

Is there a way to create a `CurrentValueSubject` that is read-only?

So you could `sink` it publicly, read `value` publicly, but could only `send` values to it internally/privately. Want to use it in a library module.

Comment: Is this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just what you want? or do you mean a value can change over time but not allow change via sending values?

Comment: If you could not send values to it, what values would you read from it?

Comment: check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520841/swift-combine-turn-a-publisher-into-a-read-only-currentvaluesubject) same question on stack

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for pointing it out! I meant sending values to it internally / privately only (updated the question).

Comment: How about just `eraseToAnyPublisher`? The client code only sees a `Publisher`.

Comment: @Sweeper I think that won't have a `value` property.

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin I think `@Published` implements `willSet` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932494/swiftui-is-it-possible-to-get-didset-to-fire-when-changing-a-published-struct/63135268#comment115325395_63135268), so it is (may) not be suitable to `sink` manually. Also, I can't add `@Published` requirements to protocol definitions (which happens to be my use case).

Comment:  I guess a custom publisher that wraps a `CurrentValueSubject` could just do this.

Comment: Who says you can't also expose a `value` property? Expose (only) as much as you need. That's encapsulation in a nutshell. (yes this is slowly converging to your `CurrentValueSubject` wrapper solution)

Comment: Related: [Swift Combine: turn a publisher into a read-only CurrentValueSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61520841)

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: there's no built in method to achieve that, you'll have to write some code for it.

Comment: @Sweeper @Cristik Thanks for your inputs! According to the suggestions I ended up creating a wrapper `Publisher`.

Answer (score 6):

The best pattern is to have it declared private:

```
private let _status = CurrentValueSubject<ThisStatus?, Never>(nil)
```

and expose it through a computed property:

```
public var status: AnyPublisher<ThisStatus?, Never> {
    _status
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I just did that too, however, this way `value` is not accessible publicly.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Which value is not accessible publicly?

Comment: Sorry, I meant [`CurrentValueSubject.value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject/value). Especially a concern when you need the initialized value.

Comment: @GeriBorbás You could just add another computer property which gives read access to only value.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a custom publisher that wraps a `CurrentValueSubject`, and that exposes the subject only at initialization time. This way, the code that creates the publisher is the only one having access to the subject, and is able to instruct the publisher to emit events.

The new publisher can look like this:

```swift
extension Publishers {    
    public struct CurrentValue<Value, Failure: Error>: Publisher {
        public typealias Output = Value
        public typealias Subject = CurrentValueSubject<Value, Failure>
        
        public var value: Value { subject.value }
        
        private var subject: Subject
        
        public static func publisher(_ initialValue: Value) -> (Self, Subject) {
            let publisher = Self(initialValue)
            return (publisher, publisher.subject)
        }
        
        private init(_ initialValue: Value) {
            subject = Subject(initialValue)
        }
        
        public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Value == S.Input {
            subject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}
```

, and can be consumed in this fashion:

```swift
class MyClass {
    // use this to expose the published values in a readonly manner
    public let publisher: Publishers.CurrentValue<Int, Never>

    // use this to emit values/completion
    private var subject: Publishers.CurrentValue<Int, Never>.Subject
    
    init() {
        (publisher, subject) = Publishers.CurrentValue.publisher(10)
    }
}
```

This way you have a readonly value publisher, and the only instance that can publish values is the one that instantiates the publisher.

Now, if the `internal` requirement you specified in the question must be taken ad-literam, then you can change the visibility of the `CurrentValue.subject` property to be internal, in this case you no longer need the static method.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a `Publisher` wrapping a `CurrentValueSubject`.

This way it can be written internally (to the module), but other modules can only read/subscribe to the wrapping publisher.

```
public class ReadOnlyCurrentValueSubject<Output, Failure>: Publisher where Failure : Error {
    
    internal let currentValueSubject: CurrentValueSubject<Output, Failure>
    
    public internal(set) var value: Output {
        get { currentValueSubject.value }
        set { currentValueSubject.value = newValue }
    }
    
    public init(_ value: Output) {
        currentValueSubject = .init(value)
    }
    
    public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        currentValueSubject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    }
}
```

> With having internal access to the `currentValueSubject` the module can freely compose it internally, while the outside world can only consume the values.

Answer (score 2):

A good replacement in this case is:

```
@Published public private(set) var status: ThisStatus? = nil
```

Use `$status` to get the underlying publisher.

Comment: The one problem with @Published is that you cannot put them into protocols